# p:treeTable creation/update issue

Tags: primefaces

Based on user input, I have to call a Web Service. The data will be displayed on a Tree Table.
The problem is that my tree table seems to be changed only in `@PostConstruct` methods.
I have a method `@PostConstruct init()` where I place the root and hardcoded the first line.
In another method(called from interface) I call the web service and complete the tree, but the `p:treeTable` contains only the hardcoded value.

Comment: why -1? If this is a stupid question please tell me the answer though

Comment: Hover over the downvote and see the additional 'flag'. Questions about code not working should include the code... StackOverflow 'basic' guideline http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. We are **not** clairvoyant

Comment: It's not about my code. I just want to now how to update treeTable with no PostConstruct

Comment: So it is about Elves? Dragons? In the last 2 sentences you use "I" 3 times... And it is NOT about your code? If you are **that** sure and obviously do not want help, fine by me... Good luck.

Comment: I don't hate, but I **AM** helping you by asking you to improve your question. You seem to not want help since you do not want to do what is requested.... fine by me... You even state in a comment that you want to know how to update things, that is also (going to be) **your** code. So why do you state the problem is not your code... No-one is going to help if your question stay formulated like this. Again... good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
My managed bean was @ViewScoped. And my TreeNode root was not static, so everytime I made a request to my page, the Tree was reinitialized.

Making my managed bean @SessionScoped, or my TreeNode static, did the job